# Finding all my owned minifigs

Tags: minifigures, part-database

Let's say I've uploaded all my sets to BrickSet or Rebrickable or something similar. Is there a way I can download pictures and part descriptions of all my 1000 minifigures?

Let's say I have a daughter who likes to make custom figures and then never put anything back the way it was before after she's done with it. I'd like to be able to print out a sheet of minifigure details so that she could re-assemble them. Or even so that I could reassemble them.

For "Parts description", ideally I'd have the text like you find on BrickLink:

- Light Flesh Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Black Glasses with White Lenses, Sideburns and Moustache, Neutral / Smiling Pattern (John) - Hollow Stud
- Medium Lavender Hips and 1 Dark Purple Left Leg, 1 Medium Lavender Right Leg with Yellow and Red Vertical Stripes on Sides Pattern

Better if it had part numbers so I could look those up.

Lots of minifigures have rear or side printing or dual-printed heads and it is often not obvious from a single photo what parts to look for, otherwise I could just use the pages on BrickSet.

Comment: @johnnyb bricklink has detail but is impractical in the extreme. Brickset has minifigs but not enough detail. Rebrickable has an API but nothing for minifigs.

Comment: Thank you for editing-in additional information, I have a better understanding of what you are looking for now. An auto-generated, customizable, detailed parts list of minifigures based on one's set inventory does sounds useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added your sets to Brickset, under "My Sets; Minifigs; View Your Minifigs" you will find all your minifigs pictured & listed by name (default). This will give you their name, ID number, and which set or sets they are from. You also have several more options to sort them by. Clicking on a picture magnify's the figure for greater detail. All of this can be printed, but given the number of minifigures you are dealing with, printing them out is going to take a lot of paper and ink and may be impractical.

[image]

If any additional information is needed, then looking up the provided figure number on Bricklink will give you the option to look at its individual components in greater detail.
[image]

Brickowl can provide you with a more compact, detailed break-down of a minifigures parts, but unfortunately doesn't use the same ID numbers as Brickset and Bricklink. These compact inventories would make it more practical to compile several figs on a single page. Perhaps Brickset may consider such a format if you were to inquire? It would be a very useful tool.

[image]

Comment: That page doesn't have all the info I need on it

Comment: I'm looking for part descriptions as well as a picture of the completed minifigure.

Comment: like "Medium Lavender Hips and 1 Dark Purple Left Leg, 1 Medium Lavender Right Leg with Yellow and Red Vertical Stripes on Sides Pattern"

Comment: The "stripes on sides pattern" part isn't going to be evident from a single minifigure display on brickset.

Comment: I have thousands of minifigures. I can't possibly keep track of which ones do or don't have back or side printing, or which head is which. I used the brickset list once in the past and it was a huge pain. For each minifigure I had to look up its inventory separately. If it were just as easy as looking at a few pictures I wouldn't have posted asking for "pictures and part descriptions". They key here is that I need a way to get to this info for all the minifigures in my collection.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 - We made quite a mess out of the comment section, I deleted my comments and request you do the same. I don't think our "conversation" here added anything of value to a potential answer. Please consider giving my answer at least a "one-up" for the effort.  Perhaps someone else will find my answer useful for their needs.  I wish you the best in finding a solution.